# Should a fisheye converter be sharp when I look through it directly?

Tags: optics, fisheye

I bought a fisheye converter some days ago. Now, I am unsure if such a converter should create a clear image if I look with my eye straight through it. I found a video on youtube with the hint that one could see something through a converter.

I cannot see through the converter I have here sharply. Everything is blurry. Is that correct or should I return the converter?

Comment: Why do you care?  What's it like when you attach it to your camera and take photographs with it?

Comment: I care, because the photos are not that perfect. Concrete: Nothing is realy focused. I thought it could be a bad device or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a "fisheye converter" would have to deform the image that is being presented to the lens, I would expect that looking through it should NOT be undeformed.  The entire point of the element is to cause a deformation curving the image into a more spherical shape.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I think we spoke from tweo different things: Yes the image MUST be deformed. All right. The question is has it to be sharp or blurry (unfocused)?

Comment: @ChristianWolf - ah, ok, I would expect that to depend on viewing position.  Lenses like that work by producing a virtual image at a fixed distance based on the distance to the subject (that way focusing still works through a range).  It may very well be blurry depending on the optics, the best bet is to try it out on the camera and see if it is still blurry or not.